# There is no error in the code. The error is related to logins in the driver

Tags: python, mysql, csv, authentication, pyodbc

```
def CSV():
    import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("E:\\bankmgt.csv")
    
    cnxn= pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=server;'
    r'DATABASE=BankManagement;'
    r'TrustServerCertificate=yes;'
    )
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

> r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};'
> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456)")

How to check if I'm logged into SSMS?
I have no knowledge about pyodbc as i'm doing it just for a project

Comment: You need to specify a username and password in the driver string.

Comment: are the parameters passed to `connect()`  missing their separators?

Comment: @JonSG No, it's a single connection string argument. See https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-sql-server-using-pyodbc/ for example

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing that out. I don't recall ever having seen a string assembled like that. Learn something new every day as they say.

Comment: I am using windows authentication so I suppose it doesn't need username and password?

Comment: You have tagged `MySQL`, but the error and code seem to be `SQL Server` related -- these are completely different products. You say `logged into SSMS`, but SSMS is the client tool used to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: "I am using windows authentication so I suppose it doesn't need username and password?" - True, but you also need to add `Trusted_Connection=yes` to your connection string. (`TrustServerCertificate=yes` may also be required, but they are not the same thing.)